# AFNetworking. Check download progress for all operation queue

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have an iOS application made with AFNetworking.
I have a singleton custom httpclient subclass and i use it to consume my api and download binary files from server.

I need to dowload about 100 files. Is it safe to iterate trough my url array and create one AFHTTPRequestionOperation for each url? My code is this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* rq = [[MIHTTPClient sharedInstance] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"...." parameters:nil];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:rq] ;
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //completion

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //manage error
}];


[[MIHTTPClient sharedInstance] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

How can I receive a feedback from this queue? i don't see any "HTTPClientDelegate" protocol or something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding progress, see [`setDownloadProgressBlock`](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/setDownloadProgressBlock:) (part of `AFURLConnectionOperation`, from which `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is subclassed), e.g.:

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes, %@", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, path);
}];
```

And, in your code sample, you're calling `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:`, so that provides the status regarding the completion of the individual operations. Personally, in my little test, I just maintain an array of my requested downloads, and have these three blocks (progress, success, and failure) update the status code of my downloads like so:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    NSURLRequest *request = ... // set the request accordingly

    // create a download object to keep track of the status of my download

    DownloadObject *object = [[DownloadObject alloc] init];
    download.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download %d", i];
    download.status = kDownloadObjectStatusNotStarted;
    [self.downloadObjects addObject:download];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        download.status = kDownloadObjectStatusDoneSucceeded;

        // update my UI, for example, I have table view with one row per download
        //
        // [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]
        //                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        download.status = kDownloadObjectStatusDoneFailed;

        // update UI
        //
        // [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]
        //                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        download.totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead;
        download.status = kDownloadObjectStatusInProgress;

        // update UI
        //
        // [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]]
        //                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }];

    [queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

You can keep track of the individual downloads this way. You can also just keep track of the pending operations (or query the `HTTPClient` object's `operationQueue` property, and look at the `operationCount` property of that).

---

In terms of downloading 100 files, two considerations:

- I would have thought that you'd want to call `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount` on the `operationQueue` of your `HTTPClient` subclass, setting it to some reasonable number (4 or 5), as glancing at the AFNetworking code, it doesn't seem to do that. I find that there are diminishing returns if you go much above that, and if all of the files are from a single server, there are constraints on how many concurrent operations can be done between a given client and given server.
- I've read anecdotal claims that the Apple will reject apps that make extraordinary requests over cellular network. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14922807/1271826.

Comment: setDowloadProgressBlock is usefull for a single connection and i use it. I'm looking the same function for the entire queue. 
Thanks for setMaxConcurrentOperationCount...the AFN code set this value at NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount (-1)

Comment: @IgnazioC Yes, I saw where they set `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, which is precisely why I point out that it's important for you to reset it to something like 4 or 5 if you're going to do 100 downloads. If you don't, it will kick off all 100 operations concurrently, and the latter ones will eventually timeout. Setting the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` will solve that problem. Always important when doing a lot of downloads.

Comment: Re progress of "the entire queue", between the operation's download progress block and the operation's two completion blocks, you have everything you need. You can either keep track of a count of pending downloads, or as in my updated answer, keep track of the status of the individual downloads in a separate array. While I can understand that you might have wanted a block for the status of the entire queue, that is redundant given these other three blocks.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. However, since as you loop through the list of items to download and create the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` objects, you are also recreating the `DownloadObject` objects. When the `downloadProgressBlock` method fires, how does it know which `DownloadObject` block to reference? Will Objective-C know to keep the specific `DownloadObject` around which was created in the `for` loop's iteration context, for when `downloadProgressBlock` is fired?

Comment: @Jason Yes, your `downloadProgressBlock` is invoked, you can either reference the index, `i`, within that block, or you can reference the `DownloadObject`, itself (and it will reference the correct one).

Comment: @Rob, thanks! Is there specific documentation on handling of referenced variables within blocks which will clarify more specifically how it would work, i.e. what rules blocks follow for determining referenced variables that were created outside of the block's specific internal scope?

Comment: @Jason Most of the discussions of variables with blocks focus on complicated issues like `__block` qualifier, the strong reference cycles and this simple issue of blocks maintaining strong reference to captured variables is so fundamental that it's given short shrift. But see [Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) and [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html).

Comment: @Jason By the way, the various WWDC 2011 and 2012 videos on blocks both have references to the fact that blocks will retain (i.e. maintain strong reference to) any captured objects.